# Understanding FFT bins interpretability

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, python, scipy

I am familiar with the continuous Fourier transform yet the more I try to understand FFT, the more I'm confused. If we've got a discrete N sample signal, FFT is a faster way to calculate DFT. If calculating the DFT is independent of frequency bins why do they prop up? For example in the code below that I took from [webpage](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10VADEg8F5t_FuryEf_ObFfeIFwX-CxII?usp=sharing#scrollTo=zaVx2vt5i2vg), we're clearly filtering frequencies, in this case the daily temperature, but again I do not understand how can you partition an already discrete sequence in further frequencies called bins. Is there a practical purpose for bins and their interpretability?

```
from numpy.fft import rfft, irfft, rfftfreq

def low_pass(s, threshold=2e4):
    fourier = rfft(s)
    frequencies = rfftfreq(s.size, d=2e-3 / s.size)
    display(1/frequencies)
    fourier[frequencies > threshold] = 0
    return irfft(fourier)
```

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  I'm not sure what you mean by `how can you partition an already discrete sequence in further frequencies called bins` ?  If the original time-domain signal is $x[n]$ then its DFT is $X[k]$.  The value $X[k]$ is the frequency-domain value at the $k^{\rm th}$ bin.  The term `bin` is just used to indicate the frequency domain index $k$.

Comment: This is a really bad way to do a lowpass filter. I suggest not using it or trying to draw any conclusions from it

Comment: @Hilmar Yes. This seems to be the trap that everyone falls into when they first come across the FFT and decide they need to filter using it.